# How to Serialize object to binary?

Tags: c#

I'm creating phone book in windows forms, and I need to write ContactList in binaryForm to save data.

What is the best way to do it? Shall I write its several fields seperately, or can I write and then read it as full object?

Contact has this fields :

- Guid ID
- string name
- string lastName
- string Email
- string phoneNumber

Comment: [Binary Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx) or perhaps consider XML.

Comment: BinaryFormatter or XmlSerializer

Comment: or any other serializer, really; there are virtually no cases when it is recommended to use `BinarySerializer` these days, but plenty of safe reliable binary serializers, or text serializers - usually json - exist

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I need very simple and easy way, Its my homework and I cant use lots of stuff like xml or json. The task was to write information about ContactList. Will be good if I do it with binary format.

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn+binarywriter

Answer (score 6):

[`BinaryWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter) does not provide object serialization. It allows you *to write your own* serialization code if you want, but you still need to do all the work - it just handles the overhead of talking to the stream and does some primitive encodes for you. If your scenario is simple, that might be fine, in which case have fun. In most cases, however, you probably want to defer this type of code to a dedicated serialization library. In many cases, that just means using a json or xml serializer. If you really really want binary, then that's fine too - [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter) is inbuilt, but has a **lot** of versioning / platform concerns, and I can't find it in me to recommend it; but other binary serializers like `protobuf-net` are trivial to use, efficient, and work on a wide range of platforms (disclosure: I'm the author, but it is free: I'm not selling anything).

Comment: Thank you Marc, it helped me, now I have more questions to my teacher :) xml and json is foreign for me yet, will find more information about BinarySerializer

Comment: @GiorgiIsaiashvili there's plenty of examples of `XmlSerializer` - just google; json.net has examples; "jil" has examples; protobuf-net has examples - they all have examples

Answer (score 1):

Class (Needs to be `Serializable`):

```
[Serializable]
public class someType
{
    public int X { set; get; }
    public int Y { set; get; }
}
```

Using Binary Writer:

```
public static byte[] Serialize(someType obj)
{
    byte[] bytes = null;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(obj.X);
            writer.Write(obj.Y);
        }

        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return bytes;
}

public static someType Deserialize(byte[] data)
{
    var obj = new someType();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            obj.X = reader.ReadInt32();
            obj.Y = reader.ReadInt32();
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = new someType() { X = 10 };

byte[] data = Serialize(obj);

someType obj2 = Deserialize(data);
```

Or `BinaryFormatter` :

```
byte[] data = null;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
    data =  ms.ToArray();
}

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter2 = new BinaryFormatter();
    var objDeserialized = binaryFormatter2.Deserialize(ms) as someType;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've learnt a lot from your code, but I cant use attributes.. there might be more simple way I hope..

Comment: @GiorgiIsaiashvili You can't use `BinaryWriter` without using `[Serializable]` Attribute.

Comment: BinaryWriter is not BinaryFormatter.  Now only is the SerializableAttribute not required you don't even need to declare a class to use BinaryWriter.